# Is there a way to access raw data stored in Youtrack?

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

In Youtrack reports, you can view the issues by two fields using creation date as y-axis and any other field as x-axis. But when you do that [like in this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHXUK.png) you view number of issues that are **currently** in the state stated in x-axis. For example, if the x-axis is the state, then you will see the current states of the issues that are created in the date intervals of the y-axis. But I also want to see the number of issues in each state in a chronological way. I want to see the states (or some other field) of the issues in May 21, 2021 (not their current states but their states in May 21).

I know that Youtrack keeps the state changes and their dates and many other data like that because in different reports, I can see that the Youtrack uses past data but usually there is no way to download the data of those reports.

I want to access all those raw data. My plan is to create some reports that are not available in Youtrack Reports, using R or Python. Is there a way to access those raw data, or a guideline to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to access raw data in YouTrack is through the [REST API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/youtrack-rest-api.html). For example, you can get the [issue's activity data](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/resource-api-activities.html) to retrieve the history of changes applied to the issue. This way you can identify how things have changed chronologically.

> I can see that the Youtrack uses past data but usually there is no way to download the data of those reports.

Report's data can be accessed via API as well. The report's API endpoint is api/reports, however, it's not documented as it may be subject to change. In this case, we can't guarantee backward compatibility. If you are fine with it, you can still use it. To see the exact request, check the network requests in the browser when loading a report.